# Sound stopped working on an HP ProBook 6550b

Tags: sound

The sound on my HP ProBook 6550b stopped working a couple of days ago. I get sound via headphones just fine. I did run alsamixer and all bars are at 100. I did check other posts but couldn't find something that helped.

Comment: Have you try boot from Live CD / USB and check your speaker?

Comment: Tried it. Same issue with LIVE CD/USB.

Mic (input) works, Speakers (output) not.

Answer (score 0):

Executing this worked for me:

```
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

This was extracted from a bigger sequence of commands posted in [this blog](http://www.dkvermalinux.in/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-sound-problem.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds probly set to default to and is a seperate audio device (read as)
Try opening the pulse settings at the top right, and select different output device.

If that doesnt work, then theres a software "switch" that requires drivers (possibly at a USB level) Run "lspci" and look for alien unknown devices.

Terminal

> lspci

This will list devices, Look for something like USB: Unknown/sound. Who knows. You can pastebin the output and ill look at it.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that there is nothing wrong with the speakers inside the computer. If not download the driver by typing in google : sound driver for Hp probook 6550b and download the relevant file. To make sure the file opens, download 'wine' from the ubuntu software centre. It is a program that opens files compatible with Microsoft Windows. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wine can't be used to install drivers for your hardware. http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-8021e00ae87d4fbfb607739af82bdb621b9d9366

Comment: Not sure if trolling or...